# NetworkImage is caching the old image

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using `NetworkImage` class to display an image from the internet, the following is the code

```
return new Container(
        width: width,
        height: height,
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
          image: new DecorationImage(
            image: NetworkImage(url, headers: {"Authorization": token}),

            fit: fit,
          ),
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(150.0)),
          border: new Border.all(
            color: Color(AppColors.surfacePrimary.hex),
            width: 0.0,
          ),
        ),
      );
```

However the image is cached, and when the image is updated on the server, the application displays the old cached image.
How can I stop the caching on `NetworkImage` ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can evict the image loaded from an URL using

```
 void evictImage() {
   final NetworkImage provider = NetworkImage(url);
   provider.evict().then<void>((bool success) {
     if (success)
       debugPrint('removed image!');
   });
 }
```

or alternatively you can add a random query part to the URL

```
int counter = 0;
...
NetworkImage('https://example.com/images/image1.png?dummy=${counter++}');
```

Comment: it solved my rpoblem but is there any way to turn off caching on network images in general?

Comment: You wouldn't want that. This way Flutter would fetch the image every time it needs to rebuild the screen (for example every frame when an animation is running). You could provide your own no-op cache implementation though.

Answer (score 1):

Piggy backing off of [Günter Zöchbauer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55125547/953000) response, I used the method he suggested but with async/await syntax:

```
Future<bool> evictImage(String imageURL) async {
  final NetworkImage provider = NetworkImage(imageURL);
  return await provider.evict();
}
```

To use it you just do the following:

```
bool result = await evictImage('http://pathtoyourimage.jpg');
```