# How to generate random CircleAvatars placeholders

Tags: flutter

I'm writing a simple app in which I have this "story" section where multiple users are displayed with their username under their picture. To generate the random pictures until I have any kind of database in place I'm using pravatar, which when opened in a browser gives me a different picture every time I reload. When generating multiple of these avatars in Flutter however, every time I get a new NetworkImage using https://i.pravatar.cc/150 it returns the same one. I then end up with a bunch of users that have the same picture. Am I not instanciating this right? Is it fetching an image only once? Here's my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < users.length; ++i) {
  activeFriends.add(getUserWidget(users[i]));
}
```

where getUserWidget() runs this:

```
Container(
 child: CircleAvatar(
  radius: 30,
  backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://i.pravatar.cc/150'),
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
 ),
),
```

Here's what it outputs:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFFHy.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image is cached [NetworkImage is caching the old image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55124849/networkimage-is-caching-the-old-image)

pravatar.cc accept Direct Image ID with https://i.pravatar.cc/150?img=3 
for your case, you can pass your index as image id

code snippet

```
Container(
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 30,
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://i.pravatar.cc/150?img=1'),
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              ),
            ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget { 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(        
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {    
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(        
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(        
        child: Column(          
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 30,
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://i.pravatar.cc/150?img=1'),
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 30,
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://i.pravatar.cc/150?img=4'),
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), 
    );
  }
}
```